# Problem in vb.net OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * ")

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am Not an expert in Vb.net still in learning process, I am stuck at the OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT").
I want to get field from table when 2 conditions are met. I am using VS2019 and my Database is MS. Access DataBase.

```
'connection Con, DataAdapter Dad, and DataSet Dst are public in Module1.vb
' this code is in Button function
Dad = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select CP_Fund_Book_No from Amount_Data where MrNo = '" & Me.MrNoTextBox.Text & "' and CP_Fund_Book_No_Status = '" & "Active" & "'", Con)

            Dad.Fill(Dst, "Amount_Data")
            Form2.CPFundBookNoTextBox.Text = Dst.Tables("Amount_Data").Rows(CurrentRow)("CP_Fund_Book_No")
            Con.Close()
```

I will attach pic of my Access Table also
problem i am having is when the data is multiple Rows then it loads if data is in one Row only the it gives problem.

DataBase Table Preview:

[image: DataBase Table Preview]

MrNo 13366 is loaded:

[image: MrNo 13366 is loaded]

Now When I try to load MrNo 13367 i get this error:

[image: Now When I try to load MrNo 13367 i get this error]

If you look at the database you will see 13366 is 3 times and once is Active
where as 13367 it is once and that is Active. what am I doing wrong here
rest of the code is working and that is also from 2nd table called Employee_Data.

Comment: Learn how to call `MsgBox` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, a few things here.

Firstly, your SQL command:

```
Select CP_Fund_Book_No from Amount_Data where MrNo = '" & Me.MrNoTextBox.Text & "' and CP_Fund_Book_No_Status = '" & "Active" & "'"
```

would be better written

```
Select CP_Fund_Book_No from Amount_Data where MrNo = @MrNo and CP_Fund_Book_No_Status = 'Active'
```

then learn how to use parameters to prevent sql injection, although that's not your issue here.

Next you say "when the data is multiple Rows then it loads if data is in one Row only".  The command Dad.Fill(Dst, "Amount_Data") will load all matching rows.  The next line:

```
Dst.Tables("Amount_Data").Rows(CurrentRow)("CP_Fund_Book_No")
```

appears to ignore all but the 'CurrentRow' row - how is CurrentRow set?  I'm guessing that's what's throwing the error.

Finally, you are being confused by a syntax error in messagebox.  In VB.NET usage is:

```
 MessageBox.Show(ex.message, "Error")
```

Once you can see the content of ex.message that should show exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: CurrentRow is set to be 0 to start with then i adds as reduce as we move in the database

Comment: yes you were rite the problem was CurrentRow as that was counting the number of rows in my 2nd table "Employee_Data" and when we search 2 things there is going to be 1 record out of many so i used ``` Dst.Tables("Amount_Data").Rows(0)("CP_Fund_Book_No") ``` and i got what i wanted.